# How to properly extract a ROI when img(roi) is not returning the right values

Tags: c++, opencv

I have done this in the past and it has worked fine, but I'm having weird functionality.  I am trying to extract the roi of an image.  Here is my code:

```
cv::Rect roi(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);
cv::Mat patch_t(current_frame, roi);

cout << (int)current_frame.at<unsigned char>(y - 1, x - 1) << endl;
cout << (int)patch_t.at<unsigned char>(0, 0) << endl;
```

These two cout calls should be returning the same value, but they aren't.  One returns 150, while the other return 37.  This clearly isn't working.  How else can I extract a ROI of an image without copying the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your input frame a colored one?

Your code works only when `current_frame` is a CV_8UC1 or CV_8SC1 type matrix.

Use `current_frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j)` to access a RGB pixel. Also note that sometimes grays-scale images are read as 3-channel matrix.

Comment: You`re right.  I was sure it was grayscale as it was, but converting the image to grayscale beforehand worked.  Thank you